# Is it possible to create Hubspot custom Flexible column which can contain other modules?

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm

I need to create a new custom module in HubSpot for landing page like Flexible column which can contain other built-in modules. Is it possible to create that type of module?

For eg:

what we can do in Hubspot now:

```
<Flexible column>
   <Inbuilt Module />
   <Inbuilt Module />
</Flexible column>
```

What I need to create in hubspot:

```
<div class="container">
   <Inbuilt Module />
   <Inbuilt Module />
</div>
```

I want to wrap other in-built module by custom module like Flexible column do.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

How to add a flexible column to your template

- In your HubSpot Marketing Hub Basic, Professional, or Enterprise
  account, navigate to Marketing > Files and Templates > Design Tools.
- In the left sidebar, click on your existing template to open it in
  the editor. To create a new template, click File > New file.
- In the inspector on the right, click + Add and search for a flexible column 
  module. Click and drag the module into your template body.
- Click and drag any other modules you want to appear in the flexible
  column. When you hover a module over the flexible column, you'll see
  blue rectangles appear where you can drop the content.

https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-pages-editor/how-to-use-flexible-columns-in-your-pages

Comment: This does not answer the question, the user is well aware of what a flexible column is and how to add it. He is searching for a way to create an own module that can be used the same way. Basically he wants to create a custom container where editors can drop other modules in.